# How to scroll via Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, scroll

I am trying to create a bash script that can control the computer (making a human-computer interaction interface). I noticed that the bash script I made basically can run any type of terminal commands in Linux (using Ubuntu).

Therefore, I tried googling the problem but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how can one scroll on an active window (current window) with only the linux terminal (mouse cursor can also be used)?

Comment: `Shift+PageUp` should scroll.  I'm not sure about how to use the mouse.  I run my scripts in `tmux` or `screen` so I can scroll and copy and paste easier.

Comment: How would I translate that into a terminal command? My C script is able to talk to a bash script which is able to activate any command in the linux terminal. I need to know how the command line can do this without the use of using a keyboard.

Comment: You probably just can't. With Shift+PageUp you're controlling terminal, not your program/script. If you want allow user to scroll its output than maybe `more` or `less` will be good for you. Make sure you read about their security issues. Check `man less` and find the SECURITY section of it.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you can use `shift + page up/down`

Comment: How would I translate that into a terminal command? My C script is able to talk to a bash script which is able to activate any command in the linux terminal. I need to know how the command line can do this without the use of using a keyboard.